# Rails Comments Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, comments

I've scoured the web All day looking for a solution to this problem. A lot of people on stack overflow have had the same issue, and I've tried all of their solutions, yet it doesn't seem to be working for me so I thought I'd give it a shot here. I'm just trying to get my page to update my comments after posting without refreshing. The problem seems to lie in my create.js.erb file, as it doesn't seem to be registering at all. Here's what I've got so far.

The Controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

    def create

    @content = params[:content]

    @comment = Comment.create(:video_id => params[:video_id], :content => params[:content])

    @video = Video.find(params[:video_id])

    respond_to do |format| 

    format.html {redirect_to "/videos/#{@video.id}", flash:{success_comment: "created!"}}

    format.js {}

    end

  end

end
```

The Create Comment Form:

```
  <%= form_tag "/videos/#{@video.id}/comments", :method => "post", :remote => true do %>
    <%=label_tag :comment, nil %>

    <%=text_area_tag :content, nil, class: "commentinput" %>

    <%=submit_tag "Comment"%>

  <% end %>
```

The app/views/comments/create.js.erb:

```
$('.comments').append('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => @comment) %>');

$('.commentinput').val('')
```

Could someone please tell me what I am missing here??? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why in the create.js.erb you render a partial but you're passing a variable to the parameter instead? You should need to render a real partial rather than a variable, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

Rails says when using remote: true on form_tag, you will need this little snippet of code tailored to your elements/application naturally. Have you tried that?

```
$ ->
  $("a[data-remote]").on "ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    alert "The article was deleted."
```

Comment: Well, you will need to change the jquery selector to the element with that data attribute on it: $("form[data-remote]"); in your case that is.  Also, not positive but maybe remote: true goes on the submit_tag?

Answer (score 0):

Any error messages on your Rails server terminal window, or in your log file?...

Tweak your create.js.erb file to test it:

```
$('.comments').append('<%= escape_javascript(render :text => 'the create.js.erb file seems to work') %>');
```

...which should add that text under each of your comments, and demonstrate the general structure of the code is working fine (if not... something else is wrong!).

Then, look at the syntax of the `render` function - is there a `_comment.html.haml` (or `.erb`) partial that will draw a single comment row?
If so, you should be able to change your line to be:

```
$('.comments').append('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'comment') %>');
```

or

```
$('.comments').append('<%= escape_javascript(render @comment) %>');
```

Comment: I threw a console.log in the create.js erb file to test its functionality but nothing shows up. I also hae no _comment.html

Comment: what response do you get in the browser developer tools? Is the HTML source of the layout sent back to the browser in the AJAX call, or are there any JS errors? PS How will you render a single comment if you don't have a partial that renders a single comment?

Comment: Yea I get the entire HTML source in the ajax call.  There are no JS errors, unless i add a respond_to js{:layout => false}, then i get a js error from the jquery file.  As far as rendering a single comment, I was just following an example I found online and didn't entirely understand what that was about, but I had exhausted every other option and was willing to try anything at that point, lol.

Comment: One sneaky fix might be to put the `format.js {}` onto the line in front of the `format.html {}`

Comment: Also, can you confirm which version of Rails you're running, please.